# How does reputation between the main site and its meta work on SE 2.0?

Tags: support, reputation, meta, per-site-meta

I noticed that the reputation from the main site carried over to meta on Gaming (at least the first upvote), I guess that doesn't work the other way around, right?

Is it then impossible to have a meta reputation higher than the site reputation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you read the FAQ on the per-site meta? I highly recommend it.

Here's [the link to the Meta Web Apps FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta):

Relevant section:

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Web Applications Stack Exchange (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges.

Comment: I had not read the faq on the meta site

Answer (score 11):

The meta reputation IS whatever the site reputation is.

> [Reputation from the parent site is transferred to [its] meta hourly.](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/no-rep-for-question-upvotes/28#28)

But badges are earned separately on the meta site.