# Meta profile's reputation area looks odd

Tags: discussion, profile-page, user-interface, per-site-meta, reputation-graph

Meta and main:
[image: meta graph]
[image: main graph]

1. [The graph has been removed due to meta having no reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56870/should-the-user-reputation-graph-tab-be-adjusted-fixed-removed-on-a-stack-exchan), but why is the main reputation still shown?
2. There's a grey rectangle ([touching the "top NN% overall" text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316777/289905)). What does it signify?
3. Why the difference in font size?
4. Why is there no <kbd>+NNN</kbd> reputation change blob?

Comment: There is no rep on per site meta, so it tracks tag badges instead, seems this is by design?

Comment: @user289905 I've spelled out my concerns.

Comment: @MarkKirby I wasn't talking about that difference, which is just a user setting. I've updated the main image to be from when the settings are identical.

Comment: @user289905 I agree with OP here, showing just empty graph isn't ideal. While not a bug, it should either just hide it, or show a message explaining why it's empty.

Comment: I see your point now, I don't think it is a bug, it was designed like that for what ever reason. Consider making this a feature request to improve the layout of the box on meta sites, I don't think anyone would argue it doesn't look awful.

Comment: @user289905 but they didn't remove it, just left a blank spot. It's not 100% a bug, just something not ideal to have, IMO.

Comment: @user289905 No, it explains why the actual graph is missing, but not why the score is still shown (without change blob).

Comment: @user289905 Good point. I'll do that.

Comment: @Adám Your edit definitely made the question better, but I am still a bit concerned, that this should be considered a [tag:bug] so that it's likely to be refused and tagged [tag:status-bydesign]. I'd rather tag this question with [tag:discussion].

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Done.

Comment: The link to `top n% overall` should be removed as well if there is no graph :)

Comment: I'd argue that the main reputation is still shown because there still are reputation-based privileges on meta, including upvoting, commenting, review queues, creating new tags, delete votes, etc...