# Not getting rep from votes on meta.codegolf.se.com

Tags: support, reputation, stackexchange-2.0, per-site-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does reputation between the main site and its meta work on SE 2.0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/how-does-reputation-between-the-main-site-and-its-meta-work-on-se-2-0)

I'm getting up-votes and badges, but no rep for votes on [Code Golf's meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/). See [my profile](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39/marcog).

Comment: This is [how the reputation of per-site-metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/how-does-reputation-between-the-main-site-and-its-meta-work-on-se-2-0) works. You do not earn reputation there. Also see the [same inquiry back on Web Apps](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18/no-rep-for-question-upvotes/28#28).

Comment: @Grace Thanks! I'll leave this here to be closed as a duplicate for others to come across.