# Do questions in a particular community's "meta" discussion contribute to a user's reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, per-site-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does reputation between the main site and its meta work on SE 2.0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/how-does-reputation-between-the-main-site-and-its-meta-work-on-se-2-0)

Or are they entirely separate from the community, apart from displaying the person's karma on the associated community?

Comment: "karma" == "reputation"?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/how-does-reputation-between-the-main-site-and-its-meta-work-on-se-2-0.  Reputation is carried over, the badges are separate from the main site.

Comment: Huh. I thought I'd closed this two or three minutes after posting. Guess it didn't get through.

Answer (score 0):

No, all Metas except for Meta Stack Overflow only show a users reputation on their main site.  There are no reputation effects from participating in these Meta Sites.

Note that you can still earn badges on the Meta sites though.