# could edits be partially approved?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, rollbacks

someone [edited my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4022868) with two distinct changes, one of which was good and one bad.
(The first improved the markup of the answer, the second introduced a bug in the code)

Could the reviewers be given the option to approve(or rollback) separate hunks of an edit?
...Or even better: could the post author be given this option?

I reverted the bad change through a new edit, but it would have felt better to rollback the bad hunk with a comment to the editor.

Comment: That already exists: see "What does the 'Improve' button do?" in [this FAQ post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284).

Comment: ok, so this may be a duplicate, but why the downvotes? I searched, could not find, and asked. Is that wrong?

Comment: Downvotes on meta are commonly used differently. For example, in this case, they were most likely used to show disagreement with your feature request.

Comment: I.e. like a referendum: 3 people voted against this feature, 1 in favour. If you're [not a big fan](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/the-meaning-of-down-votes-in-meta-vs-stackoverflow/182028#182028) see: [agree/disagree button on meta or upvote/downvote effects based on tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116010/agree-disagree-button-on-meta-or-upvote-downvote-effects-based-on-tags)

Comment: @JoshMein understood. this should not have been a feature request(or it was a bad one) since the feature existed. I changed the tag to reflect that it is a question rather.

Comment: @LonelyNeuron asked a question which has more or less the same problem-space as mine, showed more research effort and is more up to date since it was asked 4yrs later, making it a more informative read for the future. Should I now delete my question? I get a pretty stern warning when I try to...

Answer (score 8):

If there is a problem with an edit, such as it introducing a bug, it's appropriate that the suggested edit be rejected, rather than approved, and that the editor not receive credit for a "good" edit.

The reviewer can either choose to "Improve" on the edit to revert the negative change and keep the positive change, or they can just reject the edit entirely and then manually apply the good portion of the edit.

I see no reason to give partial credit to an editor who has not submitted a good edit.

Comment: I agree. I was not aware of the improve option. All I knew was that I as post author, did not get this option.

Comment: @Superole Keep in mind that if a post meets criteria for rejection, while it's certainly nice for a reviewer to improve a post to either try to salvage some value, or add their own improvements, they are certainly not *obligated* to do so.  If the post merits rejection, they can just reject it.