# Deeper Merge of StackExchange Websites

Tags: discussion

I think that StackExchange websites should be more merged. The way I see it is StackExchange is a company that provides Q&A sites, and each site speaks about different topics. I think everyone should have one StackExchange ID with global reputation (not create an account on each website and get some reputation if you are good on other sites). I think the sites should be less separated and be subtopics of the same site rather than have multiple different sites.

Feel free to agree or disagree in the comments.

Note that although there are a few questions similar to this, they haven't been active for three years.

Comment: My knowledge on java says nothing about how much you should trust my opinion on photography or whether I understand that community

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe reputation could be distinguishable between sites, and reputation earned per-site could be shown along with total reputation.

Comment: Not to mention that individual sites have different standards for questions in regards to closing them.

Comment: Re the downvotes be aware that voting on meta is different. Votes can be of the normal form but can also simply be disagreeing with the idea. I personally [don’t like this system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182028/220332) and would be in favour of a change to [separate voting for the idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116010/agree-disagree-button-on-meta-or-upvote-downvote-effects-based-on-tags) but that is the current system; think of it like a referendum

Comment: @RichardTingle I agree. I think I deserve a badge for losing almost 100 rep in two questions in one day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reputation has 2 key effects:

- A very broad indication of how much the community trusts me; if you should put stock in what I say just because I say it
- A very broad indication of how much I understand the site; if I can be trusted to moderate that site with enhanced privileges.

Neither of those things cross sites. I may be somewhat knowledgeable in programming but that doesn't mean I know anything about photography or Islam.

Equally my understanding of the standards of Stack Overflow doesn't suggest I understand the standards of other sites. (Other than the really basic stuff, which is what the association bonus is there for)

Comment: True, but someone who has a lot of reputation can probably be assumed to be more trustworthy than someone who has very little.

Comment: @nrubin29 indeed, hence the association bonus

Comment: 100 reputation can take awhile to earn, which would make you, who just joined the photography site, look better than a pro who signed up today.

Comment: @nrubin29, but a pro would quickly outpace your 100 point bonus. And in the grand scheme of things, 100 rep is not a lot. It is only meant to get you out of the "new user restrictions".