# Is it a bit cruel to down vote feature-request questions which cause the OP to lose reputation points?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, meta

We all know down votes on Meta are kind of different, they do not reflect the quality of your post. But it cause the question author to lose reputation points nonetheless!

You know, someone can spend hours to post a feature-request post, but then he get ton of down votes and lose some reputation points.

What can we do about it?

Comment: Sorry but "Can we make down vote on feature-request posts does not lose OP's reputations" sounds like a feature request to me. Since I disagree with this request, I downvote.

Comment: You can change the sentence to something like "what can we do about it?", it might have better chance to become a real discussion.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's right,Sir!

Comment: There is a proposal for [separate voting for the idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116010/agree-disagree-button-on-meta-or-upvote-downvote-effects-based-on-tags) that you may want to support

Answer (score 10):

Lix and Shadow Wizard have given great info, and maybe others will, too; but I had something to add...

One thing the initial reputation situation here can do is to sometimes force a new, excited member to slow down and take stock of their suggestions, if they are not being received well.

Sometimes people go a bit overboard suggesting a lot of things, when perhaps they are not so familiar with how things work at Stack Exchange in general. The way things are presented can have a big impact, too.

Those who are earnest in their desire to help can recover, and once someone had solid footing, it doesn't matter much, as far as reputation goes. Initially, there is just the question ban to avoid, but it's also notably harder to hit that here than on main sites.

Comment: Good points, missed them in my answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

*Disclaimer: the below is my own personal opinion as long time member in Meta. Don't consider this an official response from the team.*

I will answer with a question:

#### What is Meta reputation and what can we do with it?

Answer: it's a rough measure of how popular your requests/reports/discussions are i.e. such that many others agree with them. The more popular you are, the more privileges you get on Meta. With those privileges, you can then help moderate the site.

Meta, like any other Stack Exchange site, is mainly self moderated so the above system works just fine. Those who are accepted by majority of the users gain privileges and those who act against the majority and post things that many don't agree with will not gain those powers.

To sum this up: yes, it's a bit cruel. But that's how Meta works.

Answer (score 5):

Meta Stack Overflow is a bit of a weird part of the Stack Exchange network. It is the only meta site that has it's own reputation system.

On other metas, there is no such thing as meta reputation - your meta account is simply a child account for your account on the main site. This problem you are talking about is only relevant here ([and not for too long anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own))...

I don't feel that anything *needs* to be done because voting is currently the only way we have to voice our opinions on a certain subject.

---

Taking a step back, if you're worried about loosing reputation from a feature-request, I don't think you're looking at the situation in the right light... What is more important to you? Imaginary [unicorn internet points](https://imgur.com/rbGHXLw.jpg) or making your suggestion heard and getting feedback from the community that you are trying to improve?