# Upvoted question having no effect on rep in Code-Review meta

Tags: bug, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does reputation between the main site and its meta work on SE 2.0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/how-does-reputation-between-the-main-site-and-its-meta-work-on-se-2-0)

I recently asked a question on Code-Review meta about the scope of the site. The question was upvoted, but there was no difference in my reputation. In addition, when I put my mouse of the rep number, it is text instead of a link to my rep page.

[image]

Was this intentional, or is this a bug?

Comment: Hm? Why ask here and not on Meta Code Review? Support the site's Meta, MSO is for the crazies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's intentional. Per-site Metas don't have reputation. Neither upvotes nor downvotes have any effect.

The reputation you're seeing is from Code Review, not Code Review Meta.

Meta Stack Overflow, as the Meta site for **all** Stack Exchange (for now, at least), is the only exception to this rule.

From [New Per-Site Metas - Stack Exchange Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/):

> **Reputation is always inherited from the parent site.** You cannot gain or lose reputation* on the per-site meta. This also means that some reputation related functions like the rep graph and bounties are not enabled on the per-site meta.
>
> <sup>* however, there is one exception: extreme misbehavior on the meta site will affect your parent site reputation. And not in, shall we say, the “good” way.</sup>

Comment: so what exactly is the point of the voting system on meta sites?

Comment: From any per-site Meta [FAQ](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences): Voting here works a bit differently from the main site. On Meta, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness. Please don't be concerned if you receive downvotes – members of the community may simply disagree with your bug, feature request, support issue, or the nature of the discussion.

Comment: so it's basically using the comment voting system for questions and answers as well?

Comment: It you want to look at it that way, yes. But with a difference: You cannot downvote comments.