# Offensive/Spam flags on meta should affect reputation on main

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, spam, offensive

I just dive-bombed an answer on meta.physics.SE (I moderate Physics.SE, so the flag is binding) with an offensive flag. When this is done on the main site, the user loses 100 rep. (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22175/178438)

Shouldn't meta-offensive-flagging have a penalty attached as well? The same goes for spam flags. Suspensions are linked on main/meta, so it makes sense that all other penalties are transferred over as well.

As far as I can tell, the rep penalty is currently falling into the "hidden" meta rep (used to check for Mortarboard/Epic/Legendary badges and probably calculates the "participation" score in `/users`)

---

Hmm, this seems to actually be a bug. Quoting https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation:

> (Please note that offensive penalties, if levied by the community through spam or offensive votes on your posts here, will affect your reputation on the main website.)

Comment: On reading this post - it seems that this is a bug as opposed to a feature request. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56191/165931

Comment: @bmike: thanks, fixed :)

Comment: AFAICT - RTLTU!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ??? What's RTLTU?

Comment: Just my way to say "aRe Too Long To Understand" on fancy acronyms I see which are over three letters and not common. Found what's AFAICT only by Googling.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ah :P I'll edit it in :)

Comment: As Nick Craver said in [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160092/offensive-spam-flags-on-meta-should-affect-reputation-on-main#comment463855_160093), this is very difficult to do; indeed, I'm almost 100% sure this never functioned this way, since how we store spam/offensive penalties requires a Post to foreign key to (and said post exists in a separate database).

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely (with the obvious exception of MetaSO).  It seems like this would be easy to implement, though we need to make sure that the reputation history is updated to show why that happened.

Comment: Actually I have no clue what is shown in the rep history on a spam flag deletion. I can't find any users who had any rep docked due to spam/offensive flags (the ones I can find had 1 rep from the start, so they don't lose any rep). But I imagine that it contains a link to the post in question, so it wouldn't be hard to make it point to meta instead.

Comment: Assuming the table contains a foreign key to the posts table of the current site it would be somewhat hard. Such a reference couldn't simply point to  a different database (which I assume would be the case for meta<=>main)

Comment: This is absolutely non-trivial, not that I don't agree with the thought, but code-wise they are entirely separate databases and how the rep history recalcs, looks up posts titles, etc...yeah having it reference stuff on a different site adds a drastic complication to the the entire reputation system.  I don't think it's worth it, if the user's that much of a problem they're often removed anyway.

Comment: Hmmm, I imagine there's some tricky ways to make it happen, but the few I've thought of would create bigger headaches than they're worth.

Answer (score 9):

For those who wonder why this request is declined, Nick Craver gave the reasoning in [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160092/offensive-spam-flags-on-meta-should-affect-reputation-on-main#comment463855_160093):

> This is absolutely non-trivial, not that I don't agree with the thought, but code-wise they are entirely separate databases and how the rep history recalcs, looks up posts titles, etc...yeah having it reference stuff on a different site adds a drastic complication to the the entire reputation system. I don't think it's worth it, if the user's that much of a problem they're often removed anyway