# Reputation loss from offensive flags does not carry to per site meta

Tags: bug, reputation, per-site-meta, offensive

Meet my sockpuppet. He's only got reputation on meta and it's been that way since *February the 9th*.

[image] [image]

That's because on February my sockpuppet... *volounteered* to a [test](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/104220/how-can-i-apologize-in-advance-to-you) on offensive flags and how they affect reputation. I thought I was done doing *science* from that experiment and yet here we are, three months later, wondering why there's this mismatch between site and meta reputation.

We already know that [offensive/spam flags on meta should, but *don't* affect reputation on main](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160092/offensive-spam-flags-on-meta-should-affect-reputation-on-main) but this is the inverse: offensive/spam flags on *main* don't affect reputation on *meta* even despite the hourly account sync.

This did come in handy today when I tried to do more *science* about flags and hellbans thereof, but it's still a bug.

Comment: Letting your kitten play with your sock puppet sounds like a recipe for disaster, @badp. I'm surprised your sock is still alive.

Comment: @Mat mrrrrrrrow. *[Cats like to play with their preys.]*

Comment: [Continue Testing](http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2011/182/9/0/keep_calm_and_continue_testing_by_thesamfiles-d3knlzx.jpg)