# How does "very bad meta activity" affect one's rep on the main site?

Tags: support, reputation, per-site-meta

It is said in the FAQ (link gone, it now redirects to Tour page)

> However, please note that offensive penalties, if levied by the community through spam or offensive votes on your posts here, **will affect your reputation on the parent website**.

(taken from [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56191/350567))

But [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160092/350567) is marked as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

How exactly is that? I can't find any documentation about that.

Comment: Are you thinking of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160092/323179)?

Comment: @Laurel That one is [meta-tag:status-declined] and thus I'm sure it's not effective.

Comment: That is a very old quote.

Answer (score 7):

People get annoyed and are more likely to downvote you I suppose.

Or someone who's disruptive on meta would be disruptive on main (which results in downvotes).

Or someone has had enough and suspends you.

There's *no* direct relationship between meta and main reputation. Indirectly? It's possible

Answer (score 6):

How? Simple really.

1. Write a meta rant
2. Include a link to one of your posts citing it as clear evidence for said rant
3. ??
4. [The meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/178816)

Sometimes, the extra attention from meta can benefit you, but if you are pointing out a post which lacks merit, or was in bad shape and can't really be fixed, then the extra attention will DOOM that post.

That said, most users will not vote negatively on your posts on the main site based on your meta activity, overall voting is rather content based. The main issue here is that if meta gets whiff of something foul, then they tend to snuff it out with impunity.

As for your specific quote, I have never seen that, and I have seen *a lot* of content related to meta here.